# Installing add-ins for SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Developer Win 7 Pro

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I'm having a lot of trouble getting  SharePointRS_x64.msi to install sucessfully says it cannot find sharepoint when in fact that sharepoint is installed and running on Win 7 Pro. Because of the operating system I am unable to install the prereq package that comes with SharePoint Foundation 2010 (which includes this reporting addin).

I already have a reporting server set up for my MSSQL2008 instance(win 2008 server R2). It's working when I go to the http:\servername\Reports i'm able to launch the report builder and everything works. I'm now having trouble setting up the other end on SharePoint (different (developement) machine - running win 7 pro).

Any Help would be GREATLY appriciated.
Please let me know if what I want to do is possible.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
You need to open config file:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config

In this config find string:
Add Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="2"

Change value 2 to 0.

Values meaning:
3 - Most secure-Use SSL for absolutely everything. 
2 - Secure-Use SSL for rendering and methods that pass credentials but don't insist on it for all SOAP calls. 
1 - Basic Security-Accepts http but rejects any calls that might be involved in the passing of credentials. 
0 - Least Secure-Don't use SSL at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that installing sp2010 on your desktop is going to limit your farm. It is not going to be a fully functional farm. Advanced features like search and user profile sync will not work/get buggy. I guess now, you can add reporting services intergration to the list of things that don't work. Safe your self a lot of trouble but building a vm, which is going to be closer to your production environment anyway.

**UPDATE**

I thought it might not be supported by Foundation, but it is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326356.aspx